# Filter store records that do not match a value

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

In ExtJS I would create a filter like this:

```
store.addFilter({property: 'teamName', value: teamName});
```

This would filter all records with a teamName of value teamName.

How would I filter it so that it shows all records that DO NOT have this value for this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  [`filterFn`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.Filter-cfg-filterFn):

> A custom filter function which is passed each item in the
>   `Ext.util.MixedCollection` in turn. Should return `true` to accept each
>   item or `false` to reject it.

For example:

```
store.addFilter({
    filterFn: function(record){
        return record.get('teamName') !== 'teamName';
    }
});
```